# How to remove branches except for development and main

Tags: git, shell, grep

**Goal** Delete all branches except for several exceptions. In my case: *development, main*

I found this command but it only applies to main.

`git branch | grep -v "main" | xargs git branch -D`

I thought you could do it like this:

`git branch | grep -v "main|development" | xargs git branch -D`

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the Pipe in your pattern `\|`. Like that:

`git branch | grep -v "branchName1\|branchName2\|branchName3" | xargs git branch -D`

`git branch | grep -v -E "branchName1|branchName2|branchName3" | xargs git branch -D`

**Short explanation of the parameters**

`-v or --invert-match` The -v parameter returns all non-matching lines, which is important because you want to remove them.

`-E or --extended-regexp` Means that the pattern which you pass is extended regex which is used for the search. Then you can use the pipe to separate without escaping.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but this is the first half of the chepner's answer, *without* the explanation, and it's posted later. Can I genuinely ask what new this answer brings? I'm not downvoting, but come on.

Comment: @RomainValeri Yes ... Thank you! I have added short explanation of the grep parameters uses.

Answer (score 2):

Basic regular expressions require you to escape the `|`, which is otherwise treated as a literal character, to indicate alternation.

```
git branch | grep -v "main\|development"
```

If your version of `grep` supports it, you can use *extended* regular expression, in which `|` is the alternation operator.

```
git branch | grep -Ev "main|development"
```

Comment: Ow... you beat me to it for a few seconds ;-) Well.

Comment: Thanks to you both :-) for chepner:  and @RomainValeri .

Comment: i will accept after view minutes